# Covert timestamp in date in php

Tags: php

I am converting timestamp to a date. When I convert `2242425600` into date it is reversing date to past. My code is

```
echo date("m/d/Y",'2242425600');
```

It is giving me '12/16/1904' which is a wrong date . I have checked this time stamp in http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm. It is giving correct date.

I don't understand why the date function is giving wrong date in my code.

Comment: LOL! That number runs into the Unix [2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). That is awesome! (You can use DateTime to get around this, but wow... remember Y2K?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Date/Time object when working with dates that are larger than the 2030s

http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

From the manual

```
$date = new DateTime('@2242425600');
echo $date->format("m/d/Y") . "\n";
```

Comment: @genesis you're running 5.3 (where the datetime object is available). I get `12/16/1904` when I run it on 5.2 :)

Comment: The datetime object which works around the issue wasn't introduced till 5.3. Keep in mind that this formatting issue is part of a larger problem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: I read that 64-bit OS with PHP 5.2 is fine with this timestamp. But, how how did php programmers made it to work in 5.3? They just used, maybe exactly your method in date() function(s) ?

Comment: they probably updated the internals. btw, datetime support was added in 5.2, more methods were added in 5.3. I misspoke when I said you needed 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

This is because PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function can not handle date above 2038 and you are trying the timestamp of 2041.

> The valid range of a timestamp is
>   typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 GMT to Tue, 19 Jan 2038
>   03:14:07 GMT. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and
>   maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer). However, before PHP 5.1.0
>   this range was limited from 01-01-1970
>   to 19-01-2038 on some systems (e.g.
>   Windows).

You have to use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead.

Comment: How is it possible that it works in my example @Shakti Singh ?

Comment: Tonight we're going to party like it's 2037!

Answer (score 0):

It returns correct time. Look at this example

http://phpcode.eu/tet/

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting "Y2K38 Bug"

Please check it out here http://www.sitepoint.com/is-your-php-application-affected-by-the-y2k38-bug/